# Valgrind install specific tools only?

Tags: c, valgrind, qnx

I'm trying to install valgrind onto a QNX-based system with limited memory. I want to run memcheck to see if there are any memory leaks in my codebase. I saw on https://valgrind.org/info/tools.html that the valgrind distribution comes with a lot of tools bundled, but I only want to run memcheck.

Is there a way to install a specific profiling tool from valgrind without installing the rest?

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a way to install a specific profiling tool from valgrind without installing the rest?*

**Answer**:

AFAIK, it's not possible.

- May be try to individually uninstall some of it's packages. For example, in Ubuni it works like `sudo apt-get purge kcachegrind`
- Check an old version (s) of Valgrind which does not have a whole suite of tools.

Answer (score 0):

Is your system also very short of storage space?

Valgrind doesn't require a huge amount of storage. It's about 250MBytes for a Linux AMD64 build (which includes both AMD64 and x86).

At runtime there is no benefit in not installing everything. memcheck will only load memcheck and the core library (used by all tools). All of the other tools will not be loaded into memory.